# Why is my basic hello world nodejs app not working on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I got this errror:

*Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail*

I tried adding various repositories that other people have built as well.
Does Heroku require certain file requirements for the app to show up?

My git repository is located here: https://github.com/nathanpuls/helloworld2
My heroku app is located here: https://wyresapp.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed your app to Heroku as it is in the git repository, then you are missing two things.

1. You should assign an environment value for the port so that Heroku can use it to set the port number. It won't run the app on a user-defined port number. It should look sth like,

   `var port = process.env.port || 3000;`
2. Procfile is missing. It is a simple file that instructs what kind of app you have and how it should start. In your case, it should be

   `web: node index.js`

Comment: I updated the port to 3000 in my file here: https://github.com/nathanpuls/helloworld2/blob/main/index.js            I'm not sure where web: node index.js goes for Profile

Comment: Create a file name Procfile (without any extension) with the content (web: node index.js

) in the same path as index.js.